# Can't Write to Windows Application Log (C#)

Tags: c#, custom-eventlog

I'm having a really strange problem with an application I wrote a while back. It has worked without issues, but after leaving it alone for a while, it simply stopped functioning. I'll attach the code here:

```
try
{
    using (Process proc = Process.Start(starter))
    {
        windowHider();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        DateTime endStamp = DateTime.Now;
        endStamp = truncate(endStamp);
        TimeSpan diff = endStamp.Subtract(startStamp);

        string programSource = "applicationName";
        string logLocation = "Application";
        string occurance = "Var='" + varName + "' Var2='"+ var2Name + "' Var3='" + var3Name + "' Var4='" + var4Name + "' Var5='" + var5Name + "' Var6='" + var6Name + "'";

        try
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(programSource))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(programSource, logLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(programSource, occurance);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string message = "There was an error with usage logging. Please contact IT.";
            MessageBox.Show(message);
            errorLogger(message, err.ToString(), ((Control)sender).Name);
            this.Close();
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

When the process that was started exits, the program writes to the application log. For some reason, however, I am getting the following error:

> Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The
>   specified path is invalid

It cites this line as the cause:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(programSource, occurance);
```

Any ideas as to what this sudden problem could be?

Comment: Is `programSource` registered with the event log service?

Comment: You need to give permission on registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\applicationName  to user under which you are running code in question.

Comment: @AlG Using EventLog.CreateEventSource to generate the source should be doing that though, right? Is there a way to programatically register a program source?

Comment: @AlG As a follow up to that, running an event create command with the sourcename says that the source already exists.

Comment: Kinda. Check out the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx) -> _Create the new event source during the installation of your application. This allows time for the operating system to refresh its list of registered event sources and their configuration._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! There was something corrupted in the registry, and there must have been another corrupted component lurking around somewhere. I changed the sourcename, and it worked without any issues.

The original sourcename works on other machines, which makes me think it was definitely just something wonky with the registry.